# Read image and copy the data of that image to a text file using opencv

Tags: c, opencv

I am reading image in 1 channel and I actually required the data of the read image so that I can do some image calculations on this source data and store the result in destination.
My intention is to convert the opencv to C functions, to do this I am approaching step by step as follows:

1. Reading image and need to get the image data in a text file.
2. The reference data of other image is already there with me in text
   file, need to do some calculations on the source data obtained from
   imread with reference data which I have in text already.
3. Image warping should be done on source image and store in
   destination image.

Code snippet is as bellow:

```
char* fpath = "C:/Users/Desktop/ImWarping/test.bmp";

    for (;;) {
        Mat src;
        src = imread(fpath, 0);
        if (!src.data)
        {
            while (1);
        }
        Mat dst(640, 1280, CV_8UC1);

        // Perform Image Warping
        warpIm(mLUT, src.data, dst.data, src.cols, src.rows, dst.cols, dst.rows);

        // Display
        imshow("Original Video", src);
        imshow("Corrected Video", dst);

        waitKey(100000);

        if (waitKey(1) >= 0) {
            break;
        }
```

Can any one please provide me inputs on how can I store the src.data to a text file.
Or that will be great if any one please guide me in converting this to pure C function, I mean no opencv calls should be used.
I am trying to port this on ARM processor, so that's the basic reason why I am trying to convert to C functions.

Found the Solution:

```
char* fpath = "C:/Users/uids8702/Desktop/LDC_ImageWarping_v1.0/test.bmp";
    for (;;) {
        Mat src;
        src = imread(fpath, 0);
        if (!src.data)
        {
            while (1);
        }
update_src(src.data);
```

In Function definition:

```
update_src(uint8_t* srcdata)
{
    FILE* fpath = fopen("C:/Users/uids8702/Desktop/LDC_ImageWarping_v1.0/dst_data.txt", "w");
    if (fpath == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    static int32_t t = 0, u = 0;
    for (t = 0; t < dstHeight; t++)
    {
        printf("In main loop\n");
        for (u = 0; u < dstWidth; u++)
        {
            printf("dst data is %d\n", *(dstData));
            fprintf(fpath, "%d,", *(dstData));
            dstData++;
        }

    }
}
```

Special thanks to @Mark for giving great idea.

Comment: Consider writing a NetPBM Portable Greymap file like here - it is really easy and can be made back into BMP or PNG files easily...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22580958/2836621

Comment: @Mark I tried the above code but it only gives me 1279 value in the buffer. I actually need the source image data to a buffer and then I will copy to the local file.

Comment: Below Code is what I tried:
int main(){FILE *imageFile;
        int x,y,pixel,height=800,width=1280;
        imageFile=fopen("test.bmp","wb");
        if(imageFile==NULL){
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fprintf(imageFile,"P5\n");           // P5 filetype
        fprintf(imageFile,"%d %d\n",width,height);   // dimensions
        fprintf(imageFile,"1280\n");          // Max pixel
        for(x=0;x<height;x++){
                for(y=0;y<width;y++){
                        pixel=y; fputc(pixel,imageFile);
}   }
fclose(imageFile);}

Comment: Ugh! Please don't put code in the *comment* area - it is really hard to read! Instead click `edit` under your question and update the question.

Comment: Why did you write `1280`as the maximum pixel brightness? If your data is `unsigned char`, you should write `255`.

Comment: Sorry thats my misake, corrected. Thanks alot.