# Converting 2D array into a greyscale image in C

Tags: c, arrays, image

I imported the 2d array of Lena using a header file `(LenaArray.h); int lena [511][511] = {162,162,162,etc...},`

but now I want to convert it into a greyscale image and I don't know how please help? [Image of Lena I'm trying to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up5FX.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "LenaArray.h" 

int main () {

int i,j;

int width = 511; 
int height = 511;

for (i = 0; i < height; i ++ )
{
    for(j = 0; j < width; j ++)
    {
        printf("%d",&lena[i][j]);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844871/what-is-wrong-with-this-code-for-writing-grey-scale-bmp-from-an-image-rgb-bmp-pu/31850208#31850208

Comment: I´m not sure if `i ++` and `j ++` is Standard-conform. I think it isn´t.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the ++s. One major issue is the '&' in your printf. You don't want to print the address of the array value, you want to print the actual value. Also, you'll need to know what that value represents. Does it encode RGB values somehow? Is it an index into a palette? Looks to me like it's already grayscale. So what are you trying to do--render the actual image on a screen or printer? You'll need some kind of graphics library for that.

Comment: This is probably the simplest way for a beginner... https://stackoverflow.com/a/22580958/283662

Comment: You haven't explained the format of your array. How are the red, green and blue components stored?  The main technique is to use the relationship `float Gray = 0.2989f*Red + 0.5870f * Green + 0.1140f * Blue`.  That of course yields Gray as a floating point number on the same scale as the components. For most purposes you'll want to round `Gray` to the nearest integer to create the result image.  Something like `(int)(Gray + 0.5)`.

Comment: @Gene I suspect, from looking at the sample image, OP's image is probably already grey, but your comment is perfectly correct if it's RGB.

Comment: As C arrays start at index 0, I suspect your rows and columns run from 0..511, meaning your image width and height are probably 512 x 512.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Perhaps, but they're type `int`, so could also be packed 8-bit x rgba.

Comment: @Gene Possible, but unlikely because if you packed four 8-bit numbers into an `int` you would likely get something much larger than 162 (the first value) which looks like a single unsigned 8-bit number in the range 0..255. And, depending on the byte ordering, if it was packed, that would be almost either pure red, or green or blue or almost opaque/transparent black. It is possible it could be packed though, I agree.

Comment: Please share the `LenaArray.h` file, or a link to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char U8;
typedef struct { U8 p[4]; } color;


U8 lena[511][511];

void save(char* file_name,int width,int height)
{

    FILE* f = fopen(file_name, "wb");


    color tablo_color[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        tablo_color[i] = { (U8)i,(U8)i,(U8)i,(U8)255 };//BGRA 32 bit


    U8 pp[54] = { 'B', 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 0, 0, 0 ,
                     40, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 32 };
    *(int*)(pp + 2) = 54 + 4 * width * height;  //file size
    *(int*)(pp + 18) = width;
    *(int*)(pp + 22) = height;
    *(int*)(pp + 42) = height * width * 4;      //bitmap size
    fwrite(pp, 1, 54, f);


    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            U8 indis = lena[i][j];
            fwrite(tablo_color+indis,4,1,f);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

}

int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 511; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 511; j++)
        {
            lena[i][j]=i+j;
        }
    }

    save("test.bmp", 511, 511);

}
```